# Blender 2.,8 does not apply texture properly

Tags: texturing, uv

Following this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scPSP_U858k

at 06:58 after the texture's been applied I get:

[image]

Why are some of the faces missing? They appear in solid view mode.

This view is obtained after auto UV unwrapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mesh wasn't selected entirely when I applied "Smart UV Project". Now, all faces have texture.

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to have marked any seems. If you didn't use "Smart UV Project", the UVs are going to be all tangled up.

Andrew (the guy in the video) starts talking about Smart UV Project and how to mark seems for more intentional UVs at the 4 minute mark in that video.

Comment: I did use "Smart UV Project"; I forgot to add x-ray :P